# Why is ammonia removed before the yield is attained in Haber process?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why does removing ammonia from product mixture before reaching the yield of 20% can increase the amount of NH3 produced per unit time?

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{}$ Haber's process is as follows:
$$\ce{N2(g) + 3H2(g) <=> 2NH3(g)}$$
As you can see the reaction is going in gas phase, so removal of $\ce{NH3(g)}$ will push the reaction in forward direction i.e. in product side according to  [***le chatelier's principle***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle#Effect_of_change_in_volume).

Comment: I do understand the part regarding the shifting of equilibrium position to increase the yield of ammonia, but I am confused about how it can boost the rate of reaction

Comment: From what i understand to , in order to equilibrium to shift forward the rate of product formation will increase which in turn  increase the rate of reaction.
r = 1/2*d[NH3]/dt